# Getting Java.text.ParseException

Tags: json, parseexception

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException

at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:374)

```
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)

at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:289)

at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:76)

at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:293)

at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:143)

at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:166)
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to convert some string to a JSONObject - please post what you are trying to parse and what code are you using to do it

Comment: Where is your code ? Stacktrace is not enough to track your problem. Please look at [ParseException Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116652/parseexception-java)

Comment: its too long a JSON and I am trying to post but unable to do so

Comment: Ok here is the link http://www.gundersenhealth.org/find-a-doctor/profile/atif-ahmed/ and from this I got script tag application/ld+json .It works fine when I just copy paste it but when I get it using jdom xpath it gives me error

Comment: {
      "@type": "Review",
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "worstRating": "1"
      },
      "description": "First: "Thank you" for the opportunity.",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Anonymous"
      }
    }

Comment: The double quotes of "Thank you" were the culprit .any solutions on how to escape quotes inside json

Comment: In JSON you can use back-slash to escape a quote, however in the web data you cited they use HTML entites ( `&quot;` ) to do it. I guess either OK, depends what you want to do with the data.